# What is a Chess Number™?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with **Number** version puzzles.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Chess Number™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Chess Numbers™ | Not Chess Numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 314 | 315 |
| 273 | 372 |
| 183 | 180 |
| 290 | 284 |
| 205 | 208 |
| 294 | 300 |
| 220 | 320 |
| 308 | 208 |
| 242 | 225 |
| 199 | 198 |

For easier analysis, here is a CSV version:

```
Chess Numbers™,Not Chess Numbers™  
314,315  
273,372  
183,180  
290,284  
205,208  
294,300  
220,320  
308,208  
242,225  
199,198
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A Chess Number™ is a number that

> when converted to base 18, results in a valid coordinate pair for a [square on a chess board](https://www.dummies.com/wp-content/uploads/201843.image0.jpg) (everything between `a1` and `h8`).
>  Base 18 is chosen because it is the lowest base which has an `h` as a digit.

Here are the results for chess numbers:

> ```
> 314 -> H818
> 273 -> F318
> 183 -> A318
> 290 -> G218
> 205 -> B718
> 294 -> G618
> 220 -> C418
> 308 -> H218
> 242 -> D818
> 199 -> B118
> ```

And for not chess numbers:

> ```
> 315 -> H918
> 372 -> 12C18
> 180 -> A018
> 284 -> FE18
> 208 -> BA18
> 300 -> GC18
> 320 -> HE18
> 208 -> BA18
> 225 -> C918
> 198 -> B018
> ```

Comment: Wonderful job! : )

Comment: Expecting [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) Number™.

Comment: @WhatsUp When converted to base-30, it looks like letter-digit or letter-digit-digit, with the digit part forming a number between 1 and 19, and the letter not being an i?

Comment: @Stef Well, something like that (: